# Big Data Stacks not so open, resulting in both Ranger and Sentry being required for Security

Tags: hadoop

Confirmation required:

For various products and offerings in Hadoop, they work on certain Hadoop distributions only.

This means, in my view, that I sometimes need Clusters that use certain products that are tied to either Ranger or Sentry for Security.

Most annoying - Is there a way around this or is it just par for the course? May be I am missing something?

It seems bad that an architecture would need 2 security suites. On the other hand - it is what it is. What are others doing?

> **edited**
>
> For example:
>
> I like EMR from AWS. But I also like KUDU.
>
> EMR (for on-demand processing) works with Ranger.
>
> KUDU is a Cloudera offering requiring Sentry.
>
> So, most architects do not like 2 Security Suites.
>
> But may be my hand is forced if I want both.
>
> So, my question is, this must be happening out there, that sites are
>   choosing various components and end up having to implement both Ranger
>   and Sentry for Security. I don't like it one little bit, but that is
>   the reality I suspect.

This is my question, surely this must be what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Cloudera developed Sentry and Ranger came out from Hortonworks.

I don't think Sentry started as open source, and while Ranger did, it likely might not fully support integration with Cloudera CDH stack like Impala, HUE, Kudu, etc.

But with the merger of Hortonworks and Cloudera, then (eventually) the products will have to converge, but you'll only be required to have "both", as the title of this question implies, if you are trying to cover a range of products that one or the other doesn't support. You're welcome to open JIRAs and join mailing lists to start development interests in supporting additional platforms in the Hadoop ecosystem.

Comment: I am aware of the merger and see you like to have your cake and eat it too. I will add to the question as it was done on the iphone. I am a little surprised I would be the first one to touch on this.

Comment: So, enlighten me how Ranger could work with KUDU. May be that is the clue.

Comment: Ranger is entirely plugin driven. Given there is no existing Kudu plugin, then you need to write your own. For example, here's one for Kylin, an OLAP HBase service offered by neither EMR, HDP, CDH, etc https://github.com/apache/ranger/tree/master/plugin-kylin and you can join the Ranger mailing lists for discussions on contributing and adding plugins to an existing Ranger installation

Comment: Ok. That would be a bridge too far. You confirm my point of view. Thanks for the good advice  in 2018. Cheers